# Attaching plt.plot() on a panel created with wx.Panel

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am using wxPython and matplotlib to create a splitter window that supports commands on one window and plots data on the other. How do I get plt.plot() to attach the plot on the plotting window?

I get a popup window when I run plt.plot() and it does not accept a parent window as an argument. I need to use plt.plot() instead of the backend modules such as wxAgg because it already has the zoom and save file features and the code looks much simpler.

So by "attach" I mean doing something similar to the following:

```
self.figure = Figure(figsize = (5,7), dpi = `100)
self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
self.ax.plot(t,s)
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(panel2,-1,self.figure)
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.Vertical)
sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.EXPAND)
panel2.SetSizer(sizer)
panel2.Fit()
self.canvas.draw()
```

Where when you create the FigureCanvas instance you can specify (panel2,...) in its arguments, indicating that you want it to reside within that panel. I am not worried about making this specific example work but in general is it possible to specify the panel where you want your pyplot.plot()? I have used variables and class definitions that are pretty much in every example given.

Comment: Did you look through the matplotlib examples on embedding with wxPython?

Comment: I looked through most of them but they did not show explicitly how to implement this solution. I am new to wxPython so I'm having trouble finding the correct embedding modules.

Comment: I point those out because it seems you want to do what the examples do.  If not, your question is unclear since the only way it differs from the examples is by things that don't make sense (at least to me): you talk about 'attach' (but you certainly can't make a plot in one gui framework and attach it to another), and 'plt.plot' (what's "plt", do you mean pyplot?), etc.

Comment: Do not use `pyplot` if you want to embed mpl in your own GUI.